# Possible phase difference in equation of sine functions

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, nonlinear-analysis

Given the equation

$
A_1\sin(\omega t + \theta_1) + A_2\sin(\omega t + \theta_2) + A_3\sin(\omega t + \theta_3) = 0
$

which holds for all $t$.

It seem apparent that this implies that the phase shifts should be equal $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \theta_3$ (possibly $\pi$ out of phase which could be represented by a negative amplitude).

However I can't seem to formulate a solid mathematical proof for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to look at the answer (a geometric series of the nth root of unity), but unfortunately I could not see how I could apply that to the present problem.